# Is it possible to infuse Artificer bullets with other types of damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, artificer

I'm currently playing as an artificer in a 5e campaign and I was wondering if it was possible for an artificer to use various liquids and such to infuse their bullets with different elements besides lightning from the thunder cannon such as poison or holy water.

I am curious about this since the bullets are mentioned in the arcane magazine to be magically produced and could be argued to be a magical weapon. So I am wondering is there anything stating if the bullets produced with the arcane magazine can be infused with different types of damage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## RAW is no, but your DM may give you some leeway

UA is still playtest and this is a pretty cool idea that they may add in for additional interesting crafting, but as of right now, your ammunition choices are limited by what you can currently purchase and/or make.

There are no options for poison/holy water ammunition, which means that no, you can't craft them RAW. However, talk to your DM and see if they'd be okay with it.

### Workarounds

For poison, I don't see why you can't apply poison to a piece of currently allowed ammunition. This works just like applying poison to any mundane ammunition like arrows or even weapons. From PHB 153:

> You can use the poison in this vial to coat one slashing or piercing weapon or up to three pieces of ammunition. Applying the poison takes an action.